# Semidirect product of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group with $N \unlhd G$ such that there is $K \leq G$ with $KN = G$ and $K \cap N = 1$.

It is well known that in this case $$G \cong N \rtimes_\phi K$$

where $\phi: K \to Aut(N): k \mapsto (\phi_k: N \to N: n \mapsto knk^{-1})$

---

In exercises on classifying groups, we look for subgroups $K, H$ as above and then we conclude that $G \cong N \rtimes H$ for some $\phi: K \to Aut(N)$. We then proceed to find out what possibilities there are for such a map.

Why don't we just say that it is the $\phi$ as above? Is it because we don't want our description of $\phi$ to depend on conjugation in $G$?

Because otherwise, $G \cong N \rtimes K$ isn't useful because $\phi$ depends on how we calculate conjugation in $G$ and we want to describe $G$ independently of its subgroups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\phi$ is just any group homomorphism from $K$ to $Aut(N)$. If we have $G=KN$, $K\cap N=1$, we have an **inner** semidirect product, with the $\phi$ you have given.

"Why don't we just say that it is the $\phi$ as above?" Because there are also **outer** semidirect products, $G\cong N\rtimes_{\phi} K$ with an *arbitrary* homomorphism $\phi\colon K\rightarrow Aut(N)$.
This is equivalent to the fact that there is a split short exact sequence of groups
$$
1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G \rightarrow K\rightarrow 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused. Doesn't such a $\psi$ always exist if we can find subgroups as above in my post? I wrote down the explicit function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you ask about the difference of an inner and an outer semidirect product, right?

Comment: Suppose we are classifying groups. At a given point, I have found $N,K$ as above.Then $G = N \rtimes_\phi K$ with $\phi$ as defined above. Why exactly do we want to find $\phi$ expxplicitely? Is it because we want to determine $G$ and $\phi$ is defined using calculations in $G$? Sorry if the question isn't clear.

Comment: We don't want to find $\phi$ explicitly. The classification, say, of groups of order $12$ has a group, called $C_3\rtimes C_4$, which is not the direct product, so is not abelian. There are other, more interesting properties about this group than $\phi$, for example a presentation. But we can use the semidirect product to classify all groups of order $12$. For details, see the classification by K. Conrad [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf).

Comment: I was in the impression that knowing $\phi$ explicitely allows us to to completely understand $G$ because then we have an independent representation $G \cong N \rtimes K$ (if we know $N,K$). Maybe here is an example to demonstrate my problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193420/show-that-s-n-cong-a-n-rtimes-c-2

Comment: But at the linked question Hagen answered the same as me - we have a split exact sequence, so that $D_n\cong C_n\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: See my comment there that I made on his answer. This is my actual question.

Comment: Of course we can. There is an explicit formula for the (outer) semidirect product.

Comment: Can you please write it down then?

Comment: See formula $(2.1)$ on page $27$ in my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_54_groups.pdf). We just have $(n,k)\circ (n',k')=(n\cdot \phi(k)n',kk')$.

Comment: My problem is that your description of $\phi$ depends on how we conjugate elements in the group $S_n$. But we want to determine $S_n$ explicitely from the groups structures of $A_n$ and $C_2$!

Comment: So that's why I ask, please write down the explicit formula of $\phi$ so that it becomes clear if it uses something in $S_n$.

Comment: "$S_n$ explicitly from $A_n$ and $C_2$". This is *not enough* for an (outer) semidirect product. We need the homomorphism $\phi$, too. Otherwise we could just have the direct product $A_n\times C_2$. So there are many **different** semidirect products in general. Nothing to do necessarily with conjugation. $\phi$ is defined on $A_n$.

Comment: $\phi$ is defined on $A_n$ but seems to depend on how we calculate products in $S_n$.

Comment: No, the other way around. We construct a "product" in $S_n$ with the data coming from $A_n,C_2$ and $\phi$. The resulting group is only *isomorphic* to $S_n$, but not "the" $S_n$ you prescribe with your products.

Comment: Hmmm. But for example we have $D_{2n} = C_n \rtimes_\phi C_2$. Here we really can calculate the dihedral group just by knowing these two cyclic groups. Is this not possible with $S_n$ and $A_n, C_2$?

Comment: Actually, in general there may be multiple groups $H\rtimes_\phi K$ that are not isomorphic. All we know is that *some* semidirect products $A_n\rtimes_\phi C_2$ are isomorphic to $S_n$. We can't usually determine *which* ones are without some data about $S_n$.