# Show that $S_n \cong A_n \rtimes C_2$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product

I want to show that $S_n \cong A_n \rtimes  C_2$.

Take a transposition $\tau \notin A_n$. Then it is clear that

$$\langle \tau\rangle \cap A_n = 1$$
$$A_n \tau = S_n$$
$$A_n \unlhd S_n$$

and thus $$S_n \cong A_n \rtimes_\phi \langle \tau \rangle$$

with $$\phi: \langle \tau \rangle \to Aut(A_n): \mathcal{\tau} \mapsto (A_n \to A_n: \sigma \mapsto \tau^{-1} \sigma \tau = \tau \sigma \tau), 1 \mapsto 1$$

I'm now trying to see what $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau$ looks like, as I would like to write:

$$A_n \rtimes_\phi \langle  \tau \rangle \cong A_n \rtimes_\psi C_2$$

for some homomorphism $\psi: C_2 \to Aut(A_n)$.

How can I proceed?

Comment: As for the last bit, recall that for any element $\rho$ of $S_n$, if $S_n$ acts on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ on the right, then $\rho^{-1}(n_1\dots n_k)\rho = (n_1\rho\dots n_k\rho)$. So decomposing elements of $A_n$ as products of disjoint cycles should give us some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being of index $2$, $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$ and from the inclusion we get the short exact sequence
$$\tag1 1\to A_n\to S_n\to C_2\to 1.$$
As you said, we can pick a transposition $\tau\in S_n$, so $\tau^2=1$ and $\tau\notin A_n$. Then sending the nontrivial element of $C_2$ to $\tau$ makes  $(1)$ split, which means that $S_n$ is a semi-direct product of $A_n$ by $C_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a follow up question. Is it possible to construct $S_n $ using this semidirect product? I.e., given the group structures of $C_2$ and $A_n$, can I find the entire group structure of $S_n$? I think my question boils down to: can we find the explicit homomorphism $\phi$ such that $S_n \cong A_n \rtimes_\phi C_2$, without it depending on anything in $S_n$.

Comment: See the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193365/semidirect-product-of-subgroups/3193385?noredirect=1#comment6571783_3193385), answering your question.

Comment: @user661541 Any involutory automorphism of $A_n$ will do - but I see no direct way of constructing such an automorphism from "within" $A_n$, i.e., without actually referencing $S_n$. Only exception: $A_3\cong C_3$ is abelian, hence inversion is such an automorphism and can be used to construct $S_3$ from it.